# fn_dblog not showing up deleted table data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transaction-log

I unintentionally deleted 4 rows from a table. I tried to fetch back the deleted data using a stored procedure (got from internet). However, I was able to see my data in the result of stored procedure. Then I updated the original schema of the table and remove the primary key before restoring the deleted data and again tried to run the stored procedure and found that `fn_dblog` is no more showing my deleted rows of that table.

All other deleted data from other tables are present in `fn_dblog`. How can I now fetch my deleted rows without using any external tool?
I am using SQL Server 2012.

Edited:
I have attached a snapshot as well of ApexSQL. The last 4 rows are my data but i am unable to recover, as the redo script says:

> 00000088:0000011B:0002: ROW DATA NOT AVAILABLE FOR DELETE ON
>   [UNKNOWN].[UNKNOWN(1394104007)]

I also asked at stack overflow the same question. No responses.

[image]

Comment: do you backup your transaction logs? If so you could use fn_dump_dblog to search the tlog backups.

Answer (score 2):

From Thomas LaRock at http://logicalread.solarwinds.com/sql-server-dbcc-log-command-tl01/#.VXbj_DYpDVk

"The fn_dblog() function (formerly known as the DBCC command) is one of several undocumented functions for SQL Server; it allows you to view the transaction log records **in the active part of the transaction log file** for the current database."

The fact that you can no longer find your data suggests that the desired part of the log is no longer in the **active part** of the transaction log file.

One way to get these 4 rows back would be to restore a copy of the database to a temporary database name (e.g. DbName_Disaster) at a point in time that contained these 4 rows. Then insert the 4 rows back into your production database and drop the DbName_Disaster database.

Or you could look for some database recovery tool that fits your need.  The prices and features vary.

Comment: Apparently, you can use TF2537 to look into the non-active portion: http://antapex.org/traceflags_sqlserver.txt